# PySchool- List (Topic 6-22)

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and i am trying to solve some questions about lists.  I got stuck on one problem and I am not able to solve it:

> Write a function `countLetters(word)` that takes in a word as argument
>   and returns a list that counts the number of times each letter
>   appears. The letters must be sorted in alphabetical order.
>
> Ex:
>
> ```
> >>> countLetters('google')
>
> [('e', 1), ('g', 2), ('l', 1), ('o', 2)]
> ```

I am not able to count the occurrences of every character.  For sorting I am using `sorted(list)` and I am also using `dictionary(items functions)` for this format of output(tuples of list).  But I am not able to link all these things.

Comment: what have you got so far?  Can we see some code?

Comment: Can you show us code for the approaches you have already tried?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are really stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Use sets !

```
 m = "google"
 u = set(m)
 sorted([(l, m.count(l)) for l in u]) 


 >>> [('e', 1), ('g', 2), ('l', 1), ('o', 2)]
```

Comment: Could have hinted instead of just giving an answer. Also, telling him to use sets when he is doing a section on learning LISTS is probably over complicating. Plus, showing him list comprehension might also be getting ahead of the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: Note that you can loop through a string in the same way as a list or other iterable object in python:

```
def countLetters(word):

  for letter in word:
    print letter

countLetters("ABC")
```

The output will be:

```
A
B
C
```

So instead of printing, use the loop to look at what letter you've got (in your `letter` variable) and count it somehow.

Comment: Thanks for this, but if i pass strng to function then how to iterate over it??i tried but i am getting error when i am calling my function with strings.

Comment: See my updated answer.  It would be helpful to see what you've tried also.  You can edit your question above to paste in some code.

Answer (score 1):

finally, made it!!!

```
import collections
def countch(strng):
    d=collections.defaultdict(int)
    for letter in strng:
        d[letter]+=1
    print sorted(d.items())
```

This is my solution.Now, i can ask for your solutions of this problem.I would love to see your code.